# PHP MYSQL Hyperlinks and Form Fields

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I want to use a hyperlink to load details into an updatable form page.

I have 2 php pages. One returning the id of the last 10 records of a MYSQL query and another returning all field values for a specific record into a form, giving the end user the opportunity to update the field values. Can anyone help me link the two so that when I click on say row 3 (id = 3) of the table in the first page it takes me to the second page using the id 3 in the MYSQL query utilised by the second page, to prepopulate the form fields.

i.e. MYSQL table 'members' with 'id', 'firstname', 'surname', 'dob', and 'address'

Page 1 returns last 10 results of 'select id from members' & the id values are hyperlinks Page 2 returns results of 'select id, firstname, surname, dob, address from members where id = 3 when user selects the id 3 hyperlink on page 1, and promotes the respective values to form fields 'id_ff', 'firstname_ff', 'surname_ff', 'dob_ff', and 'address_ff'

Don't know how to promote the id '3' values to the page 2 form fields?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
# Do sql query and drop it into $members
for ($members AS $member)
{
echo '<a href="/page2.php?id='.$member['id'].'">Member '.$member['id'].'</a>';
}
```

and have on your 2nd page:

```
$_GET['id'] = whatever_you_use_to_sanitise($_GET['id']);
#do sql query with new id
```

Remember, don't just copy and paste. Think for yourself and LEARN what we did. Look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp and go through the basics.

Good luck!

Comment: If the answer helped you Alex, don't forget a + vote :) (i'm new here and need all the rep I can get :D )

Answer (score 1):

```
you can do:

    // list.php

    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM my_table");

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($c = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<a href="/edit.php?id=' . $c['id'] . '">Edit ' . $c['id'] . '</a><br />';
    }



<?
                // edit.php
    if(isset($_POST['apply'])) {

        $query = sprintf("UPDATE my_table SET somefield = '%s', somefield2 = '%s', somefield3 = '%s' WHERE id = %s", 
        mysql_real_escape($_POST['somefield']),
        mysql_real_escape($_POST['somefield2']),
        mysql_real_escape($_POST['somefield3']),
        mysql_real_escape($_POST['id'])

        );

        $r = mysql_query($query);

        if (!$r) die(mysql_error());

        header("Location: /list.php");

    }


        $id = $_GET['id']; // just an example.. you should prevent injections here
        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = %s", $id);

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $details = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">

    <input type="text" name="somefiled" value="<?= $details['somefiled']"/>
    <input type="text" name="somefiled2" value="<?= $details['somefiled2']"/>
    <input type="text" name="somefiled3" value="<?= $details['somefiled3']"/>


    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $details['id']"/>
    <input type="hidden" name= "apply" value="yes"/>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: you've got malformed html (quotes in href attribute)

Comment: come on, that is just an example :P.. anyway I've just addded some html to made the changes